# Does $\log(i^2) = 2 \log i$ holds for the branch defined by $r = |z| > 0$ and $\frac{3\pi}{4} < \theta < \frac{11\pi}{4}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does $\log(i^2) =  2 \log i$ holds  for the branch defined by $r = |z| > 0$ and $\frac{3\pi}{4} < \theta < \frac{11\pi}{4}$?

**Approach:**

**Left hand side calculation**: $\log (i^2) = \pi i$.

**Right hand side calculation**:  $2 \log(i) = 2 \arg (i)$. Principal argument of $i$ is $\pi/2$. But for the given branch argument of $i$ is $\pi/2 + 2\pi = 5\pi /2$. Thus $2 \log(i) = 5\pi i$. Hence proved that it doesn't hold.

Is my approach is correct? I need help to draw the branch of the given function geometrically?

Thanking you

Comment: Are you saying you've proved it holds, or you've proved it doesn't hold?

Comment: @T.Linnell I have edited my question. I have proved that it does not hold.

Comment: Looks right to me! You can draw the branch geometrically if it helps you visualise the problem, but it looks like you've solved it just fine without.

Comment: @T.Linnell Thanks. I suppose an array from origin making angle $3/pi/4$ will be the branch cut for this problem. Could anybody confirm?

Comment: Yep, your branch cut will be the line from the origin to infinity $3\pi/4$ counter-clockwise from the positive real line, since that's where $\theta$ is discontinuous as you traverse the complex plane.